# Unknown name value [] for enum class [enums.AdjustmentMessages] in Groovy

Tags: groovy, enums

I am using Groovy language. I use class submitted and use enum in a class as follows:

```
class Submitted {
    AdjustmentMessages adjustMessages
}

enum AdjustmentMessages {

    PART_OF_THIS_EXPENSE("Part of this expense is not covered"),
    THIS_EXPENSE_IS_NOT_COVERED("This expense is not covered"),

    String name

    AdjustmentMessages(String name){
        this.name=name
    }
```

When I want to load the page, I get this error:

```
Unknown name value [] for enum class [enums.AdjustmentMessages]
```

Comment: When you try to load what page?  Can you share the source of that page?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue. The field adjustMessages in database was Not Null. I updated the field to be Null.

Fattaneh